# signal r storing the Context.connectionID

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am new to signalr, I am want to generate connection ID to particular client and store it in database and once any updates is done by any clients will be notify to all but is it good practice to store context.connectionID to database, if not I want to know maintain connection between all client need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client invokes a function on the server side you can retrieve their connection ID via `Context.ConnectionId`. Now, if you'd like to access that connection Id via a mechanism outside of a hub, you could:

Just have the Hub invoke your external method passing in the connection id.
Manage a list of connected clients aka like `public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType>`... by adding to the dictionary in `OnConnected` and removing from it in `OnDisconnected`. Once you have your list of users you can then query it via your external mechanism.

```
Ex 1:

    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void AHubMethod(string message)
        {
            // Send the current clients connection id to your external service
            MyExternalSingleton.InvokeAMethod(Context.ConnectionId); 
        }
    }
EX : 2

    public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType> MyUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        MyUsers.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, new MyUserType() { ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId });
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        MyUserType garbage;

        MyUsers.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId, out garbage);

        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public void PushData(){
        //Values is copy-on-read but Clients.Clients expects IList, hence ToList()
        Clients.Clients(MyUsers.Keys.ToList()).ClientBoundEvent(data);
    }
}

public class MyUserType
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    // Can have whatever you want here
}

// Your external procedure then has access to all users via MyHub.MyUsers
```

Comment: @does connectionID keeps changing all the time the client reconnects..?